# Using \bigtriangledown as the nabla operator: vertical adjustment

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, math-operators

I want to use `\bigtriangledown` as the nabla operator, but the vertical spacing doesn't seem right when I use it. Can someone suggest a way to ensure everything is aligned?

For example:

```
\left (w_E \right )_{0}=-\frac{1}{\rho_0 f}\left ( \bigtriangledown \times \vv{\tau}^{s} \right )_{z}
```

Renders as

[image]

You can see that the vertex is aligned with the base. I wanted the whole symbol to be aligned with the multiplication sign.

Comment: `\mathop{\bigtriangledown}` (also don't use `\left \right` they mess up the spacing and you don't want stretched delimiters here)

Comment: Does the provided answers help? Please give feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `\mathop\bigtriangledown` does nothing at all. For instance, the input

```latex
\bigtriangledown\times\mathop\bitriangledown\times\nabla
```

yields

[image]

The reason is in the bounding box of `\bigtriangledown`:

[image]

which is already centered with respect to the formula axis, by means of the top white space.

The above is with the default Computer Modern fonts. With other fonts, such as NewTX, the output can be different, because of a different bounding box. With `newtxmath` you indeed get, from the above input,

[image]

and you can see that the triangle in the middle is slightly moved down because of `\mathop`.

So I'm afraid that a solution is font dependent.

What can you do with Computer Modern? An idea might be to raise the symbol by a suitable fraction of its depth. Here I used a factor 0.5

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,esvect}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\nabla}{\mathord{\mathpalette\raise@half\bigtriangledown}}
\newcommand\raise@half[2]{%
  \raisebox{.5\depth}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
(w_E)_{0}=-\frac{1}{\rho_0 f}(\nabla \times \vv{\tau}^{s})_{z}
\]
\[
\nabla x\quad\scriptstyle\nabla x\quad\scriptscriptstyle\nabla x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here there are two version. The first it is your code and the second is mine without `\left(` and `\right)` and the your new command `\aligntridown`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\newcommand{\aligntridown}{\raise.4ex\hbox{$\bigtriangledown$}}

\begin{document}
\verb|without \raise and \hbox command|
\[\left (w_E \right)_{0}=-\frac{1}{\rho_0 f}\left ( \bigtriangledown \times \vv{\tau}^{s} \right)_{z}\]
\verb|Using \raise and \hbox command to align \bigtriangledown|
\[(w_E)_{0}=-\frac{1}{\rho_0 f}(\aligntridown\times \vv{\tau}^{s})_{z}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]