# Using \bigtriangledown as the nabla operator: accents

Tags: equations, symbols, accents, stacking-symbols

As a follow-up to the [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560365/using-bigtriangledown-as-the-nabla-operator-vertical-adjustment) about shifting $\bigtriangledown$ to align like the usual $\nabla$ symbol, I want to have a solution, which also works well with math accents, like $\widetilde\nabla$. The accents are currently to high up due the big bounding box of $\bigtraingledown$:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\anabla}{\mathord{\mathpalette\raise@half\bigtriangledown}}
\newcommand\raise@half[2]{%
    \raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \[
        \nabla \anabla \qquad \widetilde\nabla   \widetilde{\anabla}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Not vertical aligned accents]

How do I get the accents vertically aligned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can trick TeX into thinking the symbol is less tall by "removing" (or "hiding") the top 30% of the height. With a slight modification of the provided code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for scalable wide accents

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\anabla}{{\mathpalette\a@nabla\relax}}
\newcommand\a@nabla[2]{%
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\m@th#1\bigtriangledown$}%
    \ht\z@.7\ht\z@
    \raise\dp\z@\box\z@
}
\makeatother

% just for the testing:
\newcommand\test[1]{#1\nabla #1\anabla}
\newcommand\zzz{\test\tilde \test\widetilde \test\bar \test\hat \test\widehat}

\begin{document}

$\zzz$\par
$\scriptstyle\zzz$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\zzz$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The real height of `\bigtriangledown` is a tad more than the x-height, but the bounding box extends up to the height of uppercase letters (actually a little more).

[image]

You can fix the bounding box by smashing the height and setting it to 20% more than the x-height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\anabla}{\mathord{\mathpalette\raise@half\bigtriangledown}}
\newcommand\raise@half[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{$#1x$}%
  \raisebox{\depth}[1.2\wd0]{{$\m@th#1\smash[t]{#2}$}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\nabla \anabla
\quad
\widetilde{\nabla} \widetilde{\anabla}
\quad
\widehat{\nabla} \widehat{\anabla}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]